# JAX-RS POST method 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, ajax, post, jax-rs, oracle-jet

I know there are some threads with the same question, however I don't get it running properly. I'm still very new at this.

I have a JAX-RS server running:

The `GET` method works. The `POST` method does not.

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response post(Movie movie){
    System.out.println("In the POST method");

    String result = movie.toString();

    return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();
```

In my Oracle JET Client I want to make a post:

```
addMovie = function(){
    console.log("post sent");
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/MovieRestService/resources/movies",
        headers: {

            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },           
        data:  
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        name: "test",
                        director: "test",
                        year: 234
                    },
        success: "success",
        dataType: 'application/json'
      });
```

It keeps giving me a `415 Unsupported Media Type` error. 
Something that seems a little bit odd to me is that in the response header the content type is text/html `Content-Type: text/htlm`

Anyone has a solution?

**EDIT:**

After lots of searching on the web I finally managed to find out what the real problem is... It seems that Glassfish 4.1.1 has a bug in it what was causing the problems while making a post to my server...

Comment: Try setting ``contentType: 'application/json', dataType: 'json'``

Comment: @gmaslowski not working for me. Still get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
    var url = 'http://localhost:8080/MovieRestService/resources/movies';
    var sucessCallback = function(response) {...}
    var data = JSON.stringify({
                    id: 2,
                    name: "test",
                    director: "test",
                    year: 234
                });
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: POST,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        context: this,
    }).success(sucessCallback);
```

Comment: When I use this, it is seen as a `GET` method. It returns all the records from the database

Comment: Sorry , I forgot to add method Post.

Comment: Yes I already added that manually, however it still throws the same error..

Comment: @rssd I thought your problem was in the data format you are sending. To eliminate data format problem,  try to send request witout data.

Comment: my main problem was the lack of contentType on the ajax post thank you.